# Materialize issues with Jquery in Rails 6

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, materialize, webpacker

I'm having problems getting my javascript elements of Materialize to work with rails 6.  I'm using the 'materialize-sass' gem.

Here's my javascript file

```
import 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize'


require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

// Uncomment to copy all static images under ../images to the output folder and reference
// them with the image_pack_tag helper in views (e.g <%= image_pack_tag 'rails.png' %>)
// or the `imagePath` JavaScript helper below.
//
// const images = require.context('../images', true)
// const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true)


//Floating Action Button
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.fixed-action-btn');
    var instances = M.FloatingActionButton.init(elems, {
      direction: 'up'
    });
  });

//Datepicker
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker');
  var instances = M.Datepicker.init(elems);
});

//Dropdown Menu
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log("run")
  $('select').formSelect();
});
```

The errors I'm getting in my browser

"Uncaught TypeError: $(...).formSelect is not a function"
"jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).formSelect is not a function TypeError: $(...).formSelect is not a function"

Let me know if I need to add more details.

Comment: Please post your package.json file

Answer (score 3):

You don't have jquery setup.  Try the following:

```
yarn add jquery
```

then in config/webpack/environment.js add the following:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery',
  'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
}))

module.exports = environment
```

also you have Turbolinks installed so you need to use:

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
  ...
});
```

to listen for page loads.

Comment: Hey, I ran those steps and I'm still getting the whole "formselect" is not a function error

Comment: Just updated my answer.  Materialize looks for window.jQuery to see if jQuery is initialized.